# Is it possible to import multiple namespaces at once?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Often in my Projects I have to use sub-namespaces of a common main Namespace.
As example:

```
using MyProject.MyEnums;
using MyProject.MyBusinessLogic;
using MyProject.MyGUI;
...
```

Now I'm wondering though if there is any shortcut possible to reduce the number of usings (with greater Projects as good as 20!) to one. As example (I know it doesn't work): `using MyProject;`  instead of the 3-5 usings in the example above.

Comment: What is your concern with having multiple `using` lines?

Comment: @mjwills It is so that it is often easily overlooked to include another one (one of my collegues wants to create usings manually instead of using the refactor function on right click), and as my collegues want to have the usings in a specific Format (first the System usings/automatic then the ones added).......it would help a lot to reduce my working Overhead if I could reduce the number of usings. Also if it increases to 10-20......it gets a bit colluted to look through if I'm using the correct class or had used the wrong using.

Comment: If you had installed resharper that it can help you to write the using.

Comment: `first the System usings/automatic then the ones added` - https://dailydotnettips.com/automatically-place-the-system-directives-first-when-sorting-usings-option-in-visual-studio/

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ea5352cc-43c9-4a10-89e5-9afae5fc9c3b/is-it-possible-to-use-wildcard-instead-of-listing-out-all-the-namespaces?forum=csharpgeneral may be of interest.

Comment: You can crate a project template that contains all the using statements.

Comment: There is "Edit-IntelliSense (or just right click inside cs-file)-Organize Usings-Remove and Sort Usings" menu action. It would imply certain order and should be used as a standard. If number of usings is too big, then it seems class inside is doing too much or team is too obsessed with namespaces (from `MyEnums` it's probably a latter case).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your classes split into folders in your project. Set the Namespace provider of your folder to false. Saves spamming your classes with multiple usings.

[image]